# Best C/C++ Network Library

Tags: c++, c, networking

I haven't done work in C/C++ for a little bit and was just wondering what people's favorite cross platform libraries are to use.

I'm looking for something that is a good quick and dirty library as well as a library that is a little more robust.  Often those are two different libraries and that's okay.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

Aggregated List of Libraries

- [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is really good.
- [Asio](http://think-async.com/Asio/) is also available as a stand-alone library.
- [ACE](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/ACE.html) is also good, a bit more mature and has a [couple](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604647) of [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201795256) to support it.
- [C++ Network Library](http://cpp-netlib.org/index.html)
- [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)
- [Qt](http://www.qt.io/developers/)
- [Raknet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/)
- [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) (C++)
- [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/) (C Library)
- [nng](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng) (C Library)
- Berkeley Sockets
- [libevent](http://libevent.org/)
- [Apache APR](http://apr.apache.org/)
- [yield](https://github.com/glycerine/yield)
- Winsock2(Windows only)
- [wvstreams](http://code.google.com/p/wvstreams/)
- [zeroc](https://zeroc.com/)
- [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)
- [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) (Cross-platform C library)
- [SFML's Network Module](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/#network-module)
- [C++ Rest SDK (Casablanca)](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk)
- [RCF](http://www.deltavsoft.com/doc/rcf_user_guide/Intro.html#rcf_user_guide.Intro.WhatIsRcf)
- [Restbed (HTTP Asynchronous Framework)](https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed)
- [SedNL](http://github.com/zenol/sednl)
- [SDL_net](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/)
- [OpenSplice|DDS](http://www.prismtech.com/vortex/vortex-opensplice)
- [facil.io](http://facil.io) (C, with optional HTTP and Websockets, Linux / BSD / macOS)
- [GLib Networking](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-gnetworking.h.html)
- [grpc](http://www.grpc.io/) from Google
- [GameNetworkingSockets](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/GameNetworkingSockets) from Valve
- [CYSockets](https://github.com/OmarAflak/Asynchronous-Socket-Class-C-Windows) To do easy things in the easiest way
- [yojimbo](https://github.com/networkprotocol/yojimbo)
- [GGPO](https://github.com/pond3r/ggpo)
- [ENet](http://enet.bespin.org)
- [SLikeNet](https://github.com/SLikeSoft/SLikeNet) is a fork of Raknet
- [netcode](https://github.com/networkprotocol/netcode)
- [photon](https://www.photonengine.com) is closed source, requires license to use their sdk
- [crossplatform network](https://bitbucket.org/ptroen/crossplatformnetwork) - open source non blocking metatemplate framework built on top of boost asio

Comment: There is a free, open-source version of Qt and you can create commercial software with that as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352896/qt-commercial-licenses

Comment: You might want to consider the standalone version, header only, version of Asio if you do not want to link against Boost, or add boost to your project. http://think-async.com/Asio

Comment: At all times before anyone tries to use any of these frameworks he/she should read the documentation. For example asio and boost::asio dropped support for a large amount of older compiler versions. In my case now I am unable to use newer versions of these libraries for mature projects.

Comment: You are better off looking for the **asio** library [here](http://think-async.com/Asio/). Note that there is a "standalone version" that is not dependent on the rest of Boost. There seems to be a lot of documentation (e.g. the PDF version is 1425 pages!). (Sorry for not editing this into the answer proper but I wasn't allowed - not enough points? Anyone with the creds to do so for me, please?)

Comment: C++ Rest SDK (Formerly known as Casablanca) at https://casablanca.codeplex.com/ is a good contender to this list.

Comment: I suggest to add two more libraries: [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) and [plibsys](https://github.com/saprykin/plibsys).

Comment: Winsock isn't a library. It is an API/ABI backed by a set of system calls.

Comment: @Ed Rowlett-Barbu: I'm wondering why you said the standalone ASIO library is header only? It's not!

Comment: Take a look at the [evpp](https://github.com/Qihoo360/evpp) and [libsocket](https://github.com/dermesser/libsocket)

Comment: [cpp-httlib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) is great if you need something very light, with no dependencies, but still having a nice C++ interface.

Comment: I would not recommend SFML's network module. I'm here looking for another because of problems I've run into that I've seen others run into as well.