# Networking in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, networking, sockets

I am a begginer C++ programmer. In C#, I used the System.Net.Sockets.Socket class, which represents a networking socket, to create/connect a server. How can I do the same thing in C/C++? Are there any classes like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In windows theres a library called winsock.dll.

In Unix, you can use unix sockets

Then, theres boost sockets

[beej guide to internet sockets](http://www.silicontao.com/ProgrammingGuide/other/beejnet.pdf)

[windows sockets](http://www.snible.org/winsock/)

[boost networking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading [beej's guide to Network Socket programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It is a really good source full of good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are not a fundamental part of either C or C++. If you are on Windows, start off with [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've done a little bit with libcurl, this question has tonnes of answers:

[[Best C/C++ Network Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)

...OK to be fair, libcurl doesn't work directly with sockets, so maybe it's not what you're looking for. But it does support a great many protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` in C#, you can use `System::Net::Sockets::Socket` in C++/CLI--a language which is a .NET flavor of C++.