# C network programming?

Tags: c, unix, posix, bsd

What libraries are the best (in terms of performance) for network programming in C on windows and UNIX?

I'm quite interested with respect to high frequency trading.

I have heard about BSD and POSIX but I wasnt sure if there were faster performance-specific libraries?

Comment: What are your requirements? Have you demonstrated that the OS-provided networking facilities do not meet those requirements?

Comment: The OS-provided networking is quite capable of saturating a gigabit ethernet connection.  How fast is your connection to the internet?

Comment: What do you mean by OS-provided networking facilities? I wish to write some server-client demo programs in C and it was my understanding the original C standard contains no networking libraries, so I would have to use something else (like bsd, POSIX etc), atleast in the case of Windows? Im unsure about UNIX

Comment: The C Standard provides no networking libraries - 'tis true.  But if you're working on a Unix-like platform, the 'standard' (as in 'provided by the OS') libraries will include BSD sockets, and those will perform well for you.  On Windows, there's probably a wholly different interface (WinSock?).  Or you can use Cygwin or Mingw to provide BSD sockets.  They're all likely to perform well enough too.

Comment: @Jonathan WinSock is derived from BSD, so they are similiar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)

Comment: It depends a lot of what you need to do besides networking. Give some more details and people will start to advocate their favorite thread or non-thread library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way would be to use the OS's networking functions: `socket()`, `setsockopt()`, `connect()`, `listen()`, `send()`, `recv()` etc. etc.

There are subtle differences between them on several OS's.

To cope with this, there are wrappers around them in several libraries, e.g. in Qt (at least, IIRC). I don't think anything will noticeably slow down if you use them...

Comment: Hi, do i just need to include windows.h to get access to those?

Comment: I suppose so, but I am not sure. Don't program much under windows.

Comment: A great resource on this type of low level network programming is http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ . The content is mostly unix focused but has some commentary on usage in windows.

Answer (score 0):

What about ZeroMQ. [http://www.zeromq.org/][1]

It's a faster, easy to code and also can be used as Message Queue.

Comment: You should mention some of the multiple options available instead of must a single one.