# Cross platform C++ UDP socket library

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

Can somebody recommend a free C++ open source library which I will use to build a networked game using UDP. Must be available for Windows/Linux/Mac. As lightweight as possible please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library

Comment: You can use Qt if you don't need static linking.

Comment: The lightest-weight solution is simply to call the BSD-style C socket functions directly; they are already available on all of the OS's you mentioned, and they work the 99.9% the same on each (the main difference is you need to call WSAStartup() before using them, in the Windows version only).  UDP sockets are simple enough to use that a C++ wrapper library isn't really going to save you very much work anyway.

Comment: @Jeremy I want to avoid any Windows specifics. I've seen some of this code using sockets which has a fair bit of #ifdefs in it.

Comment: I don't think you'll be avoiding Windows specifics so much as moving them from your code into the network-library's code.  FWIW, I count less than a dozen such #ifdefs in my networking library (which I don't think you would consider "lightweight", but FWIW it's here:  http://www.lcscanada.com/muscle )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [SDL_Net](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/)? Not C++ really, but is lightweight and cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

http://enet.bespin.org/

A very advanced C UDP-based library, with multiplexing, reliable/unreliable/unsequenced/fragmented delivery. Cross platform. Used and created for an established open source game (Cube 2: Sauerbraten), and if you nibble at its mailing list, you'll see that it's sometimes used for commercial games too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using networking myself in C++ but I would give [Boost asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/) a try if I had to do  networking.

Comment: If the OP is new to Boost: The whole distribution is quite big (about 100 MB with just the sources), but Asio by itself occupies about 2.22 MB in the 1.4.80 version. You might have to add a few dependencies, but it should keep small enough.

Comment: I haven't used Boost (but hear it mentioned a lot) and 2.2 MB is prohibitive.

Comment: ASIO also exists as a stand alone library