# Twisted alternative in C++

Tags: c++, events, networking, twisted

I'm looking for something like Twisted in Python (event-driven networking engine). I've found Boost:Asio but it is hard for me. So I need something much easier (without low level programming).

Comment: You probably shouldn't go the C++ route then...

Comment: If you don't want low level programming, why are you using C++?

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz Since when are you forced to go low level in C++? The whole point of C++ is to have high level abstractions to allow libraries to be as high level as they need on their interface, but still implement low level stuff if needed.

Comment: Did you look in here: "Best C/C++ Network Library [closed]"(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend to start with Asio from implementing and changing the examples.

Boost.Asio is the-state-of-the-art today and one of the easiest way to start asynchronous/event-driven networking programming with C++.

So give Boost.Asio 2nd chance as it is one of the best tools around.