# Detecting network connection

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

Is there a cross-platform library that allows managing of network connections? Are, for example, Qt libraries capable of this? If so, what classes should i look for?

By managing network connections i mean detecting them and monitoring them. Platforms supported by library must be Windows and Linux. The library must be on c++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you actually looked? I mean, googling for "cross platform C++ network library" brings up a bunch of resources, including previously answered SO questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678367/c-sockets-library-for-cross-platform

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best C/C++ Network Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `<QtNetwork>`
and read about QNetworkInterface