# How to get input form the website using C++?

Tags: c++, file-upload, c++11, web, io

I am trying to get a file "input.txt", that is hosted on a website "site.com" use it in my c++ program.  The file "input.txt" has the format `string1 string2 int`, is there a way I can do that in C++ that is portable, so someone on a Linux machine can just run my code and be able to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no standard network libraries in c++, so you may use some 3rd party libraries.You can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library).

When you are on a Linux machine, you can use the POSIX Sockets, and [here](https://www.openlearning.com/u/david/CNetworking) is a example.