# How do i input a keyword into a search engine (yahoo, bing, Google) using c++

Tags: c++, web-services, gwt, web

How do i input a keyword into a search engine (yahoo, bing, Google) using c++ program

Is it possible to run it on backend without browser appearing/booting. If yes, how?
If not, how can i do it? Do i have to refer to api's/ libraries of browser and search engines?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Use the result from the search engine or show the search in the browser?

Comment: @Mads I want to extract urls and page sources out of returned page result searches from search engines, but in order to do that i need to first allow user to input their search keyword, thus the question.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is I believe so:

If you can use a library that allows you to send HTTP requests to an URL, then you should be able to do it simply by loading the webpage at url: `http://www.google.com/?#q=your+query+here` and parse/display the XML/HTML yourself.

I have never actually used C++ to do anything like that, but [one of these links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library) might be a good starting place.