# What possible choices do I have to implement a high-performing low-level Linux TCP/IP Socket client for 5 concurrent connections?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, sockets, tcpclient

I have a scenario where I'm trying to research (and utilise) the best available C++ Library to  fulfill the following requirements:

Develop a low-level Linux based TCP/IP Socket CLIENT application, that, 
   a) can connect to a 3rd party SERVER via up to 4-5 sockets
   b) POLL it every 200 milli seconds (with a small piece of data) - via all 5 sockets
   c) and. based on the reply it gets, *occassionally*  send an XML-formatted request(a rather important one).

---

The most important factor in this design is to be PERFORMANCE and latency + minimal development time(for me)

---

I already have a (past) background doing these things in C(and some C++), but have done some research and come up with a short=list of possible ready-made Socket libraries to use.

a) Boost::Asio
b) http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/index.html - C++ Sockets Library
c) other possible "small scale" and minimally functional libraries

OR,
design and Write it my self , using BSD sockets and some multi-threading options(which was my original plan)

Anyone with any ideas on the best and most time-saving  route to take ??

Thanks folks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best C/C++ Network Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)

Comment: Something seems inconsistent. Your performance requirements are absolutely minimal, so why is performance the most important factor? It's like saying, "I want to build a bridge for ants, and the most important thing is that it be able to carry lots of weight."

Comment: Fair enough. I  don't (and neither do many of the members on it)  (fully) really resonate - nor agree with -the some of ways of StackOverflow- generally anyway.  PLease feel free to delete the question and I will forget all about this. Blessings from the Light, MITreYaBuddha. . .

Answer (score 2):

I believe **Poco C++ Library ( http://pocoproject.org/ )** is what you need.
it is a highly protective and the performance very impressive and mainly for networking + it is really well documented.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for providing me with a constructive answer. Appreciate it.