# Create a web server with nodejs/http-parser

Tags: c++, http

I want to create a small web server in c++ with http-parser from here [nodejs/http-parser](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser), I downloaded and I compiled what should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a way to communicate using TCP/IP in order to implement the HTTP server; depending on your case, you may also need to use other protocols, like UDP (for instance, if you need to resolve a domain name, you will typically use DNS) or ICMP.

If your application is running by an Operating System, take a look at its documentation about the networking facilities it can provide you. For instance, many operating systems provides a [POSIX sockets API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) that will help you dealing with network devices and protocols.

If you prefer, you can use one of the [networking libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library/118968#118968) already written, provided they support your environment. They can help you with a useful abstraction of the network, so you can concentrate better on your application.

On the other hand, if your application will not be running by an Operating System, the first thing to do is to find some [internet protocol suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) that you will be able to use in your particular environment.

If you don't find one, you obviously need to implement everything by yourself.