# c++ Console application connection to android app

Tags: android, c++, server, console-application

I have to make a connection between android app and c++ console application:
The console application is suppose to be the client side which has 4 commands to get data from the server which is the android device. In other words I need to display the device info (BT/WIFI on/off, BATTERY LVL) in the console application.

I created the client side and I also have the code for the things I have to check(if BT is on for example).
The only thing I'm missing is the connection between these, I have no experience in server code, and I need your help with this, how is this done or links for tutorials cause I didn't find some.

the android code:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //IMEI init
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

    //software version init
    PackageInfo pInfo = null;
    try {
        pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int SoftwareVersion = pInfo.versionCode;


    //battery lvl init
    battery = Library.getBatteryLevel(this);

    //android id init
    android_id = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    //android availability init
    internetaval = Library.isNetworkAvailable(this);

    //finish init  <<~~




    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv.setText(" " + internetaval);

    Library.setWifi(this,false);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is too broad and subject to being closed, I will give you an overlook clue to be implemented.

Using Java network APIs (socket programming) you should pick a port number and start listening on. The key thing here is that your Android device and your computer running that C++ app must be connected to the same network (for example a WLAN or LAN).

In this case both your devices will be assigned two unique IP address, you can also set them manually.

In your client side (C++), you should create a TCP socket and connect to IP address of your Android device given its port number. So, using this way you can connect your C++ to your Java server running in your Android app. Also in other side, you should accept incoming connects in your Android app using Java socket APIs.

- [Client Example in C](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_client_example.htm)
- [Java Networking Examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm)

**Suggestion:** Never create your apps from scratch, always use well-known [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library). This makes development process more quicker and also more enjoyable. `:)`

Comment: If this is to be distributed to end users, bluetooth might be better, because it includes service discovery. WLAN might additionally need something like uPNP a that is quite a lot of additional complication for setup.

Comment: @JanHudec You're right, however many computers might not have bluetooth adapters. Additionally bluetooth's range is small (10m).

Comment: @JanHudec Also in service discovery point of view, a simple solution would be scanning a range of IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer!

Comment: @ZachBublil Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer, if you found it helpful.

Comment: @ZachBublil My mean by "accept" is marking it as accepted. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: 'C++ Client Example'. That is not C++. It's C.

Comment: @greenapps Oh, sorry, you're absolutely right. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have created an C++ for your Android device using cross-compiler. I can launch and execute your own binary app has been builded for your Android app.
The most common usage is to extract to a folder inside `/data/data/yourapp/somewhere` start your own c++ app. Then, launch this app in a separate thread.
To interact between Java Android and your C++ app I can offer your to major variants for linux OS:
1. TCP-IP server-client.
2. Use Pipe interaction: FIFO (file in - file out).
3. Or just simple run your c++ app with some input arguments with a result. Of course, you read sdtout and write to stdin as in usual OS.

If you mean a usual Windows/MacOS/Linux app, you have to interact with the Phone using WiFi/BlueTooth/NFS/Lan/adb(Log)/ connection, is your device rooted. That is, first of all you have to define which hardware you have to use. But the major interact in this case: TCP-IP.