# Should I use C++ for network-programming?

Tags: c++, network-programming

I started learning C++ last year and I finally feel comfortable to the point that I've started using other libraries and making games and stuff. When I first started learning it was because I was fed up with problems I couldn't fix in major game engines and thought, why not learn how to make my own. But now I've advanced to the point that I wanna learn networking for the sake of my games (multiplayer and etc.). I've been doing some research and I've learned that there are easier languages to learn about networking with and that C++ isn't a language that offers much support for this. I'd also like to eventually make websites that interact with my games. So I guess what I'm really asking is what path should I take? Learning a new language that caters more to what I'm trying to do or trying to extend my current knowledge in C++ and if so why one over the other?.

**EDIT**: I know that there are libraries out there for network-programming in C++, I'm not asking what the names of them are I'm just asking if it'd be easier to learn and use them versus learning and using a language more tailored to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best C/C++ Network Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library)

Comment: IMO Java is much better for networking, especially with Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think C/C++ is a perfectly valid language to start learning network programming in. It will allow you to control the packets to a very large extend.

For reading I recommend https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/, it's mostly about unix networking but has several notes on working with the winapi as well.

Note that to get everything to work across platforms you may have to find a library.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this :)