# I send an websocket package,but the server just answers 400

Tags: c++, sockets, url

Here is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKow9.png)
I make a socket connection by usual,and just want to send the headers.
And the //was the headers which I had tired to add,but it did not work.
could anyone give me some advices?

Comment: Might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118945/best-c-c-network-library

Answer (score 0):

You can't just open a socket and hope for the best - you have to actually implement the protocol!

The host is `127.0.0.1`. `127.0.0.1/test` is not a host; TCP/IP has no earthly idea what to do with that information. Your WebSockets implementation (or, ideally, [an existing one that you use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118945/560648)) will know how to handle the URL `127.0.0.1/test` after opening a socket to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Well,I have found the libs to handle this on linux,but I has not found any lib or other information to describe how to deal with the the whole url above.

Comment: And I have made the websocket package by streamstring,maybe I should read some api on MSDN?